# JavaFx TableView how to tell if ScrollBar is visible

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, scrollbar

Based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693136/javafx-how-to-freeze-the-position-of-some-columns-in-tableview) (Option #1) I am creating a fixed column by using 2 `TableView`s in a `SplitPane`.
The `TableView` that shows the other columns (not the fixed one) may get so wide that a `ScrollBar` is displayed, for which I have to compensate with `-fx-padding: 0 0 13px 0;` in order to keep the `TableRow`s of both `TableView`s aligned.

So I have to figure out now whether a `ScrollBar` is being displayed or not or find a completely different way to ensure the `TableRow` alignment. The obvious way unfortunately doesn't seem to be working. (The `ScrollBar` is not `null`, I just didn't post the code to ensure that)

```
ScrollBar horizontalScrollBar = (ScrollBar) lookup(".scroll-bar:horizontal");
horizontalScrollBar.visibleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(newValueobservableScrollBar);
});
```

For some reason the Listener is not fired when the `ScrollBar` appears or disappears.

Comment: I guess the `ScrollBar` is completely removed from the scene instead of just made invisible. (Which would be the more efficient approach for layout performance anyways... You could listen to this by adding a listener to the `scene` property and checking for `null`, but the exact way the `ScrollBar` is displayed/hidden is an implementation detail and the code could break any time the java runtime is updated...).

Comment: So you mean basically just replacing the ```visibleProperty()``` with ```sceneProperty()```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to figure out whether a particular scrollbar is visibile I first had to find it, so I looked up all the scrollbars on that particular table.

```
Set<Node> scrollBars = itemsTableView.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
```

Then filter the set in order to retrieve the specific scrollbar I was looking for (horizontal in my case)

```
Optional<Node> horizontalScrollBar = scrollBars.stream()
          .filter(node ->
            ((ScrollBar) node).getOrientation().equals(Orientation.HORIZONTAL))
          .findAny();
```

And then attach the listener to the visibility-property of the scrollbar

```
horizontalScrollBar.ifPresent(node ->
          node.visibleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    if(newValue)
                    {
                        columnTableView.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 0 13px 0;");
                    } else
                    {
                        columnTableView.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;");
                    }
              })
        );
```

Almost looks kinda simply right? Well, it is, as soon as you have figured out that

```
lookup(".scroll-bar:horizontal");
```

does NOT return the horizontal scrollbar but the first (vertical) one. And unless you realize that, your Application will behave kinda mysteriously.